# IntelliJ - unfolding Angular imports when using auto formatting/reformat

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have problem with auto formatting using IntelliJ. When  I press `Ctrl+Alt+L` IntelliJ unfolds many imports from Angular from one to many lines like like in an example below:

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  QueryList,
  ViewChild,
  ViewChildren
} from '@angular/core';
```

But previous was everything in one line:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, QueryList, Renderer2, ViewChild, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';
```

Can I force IDE to not to unfold these imports into so many lines?

**Edit**

[My editor settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Ale.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Intellij -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> JavaScript select "ES6 import/export" = "Do not wrap"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see `ES6 import/export`. I add screenshot. Please take a look.

Comment: In `Wrapping and Braces` tab